# WSUS Update on C#

Tags: c#, winapi

How can I get now downloading patches?
The problem is: I start download and close my application, and when I start it I need to know what is going on there.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please read it and try to clarify it so other people have a chance to understand what you want. http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Some samples: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=18774
Doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms744624(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I aready found approach. I save the list of update ids in registry, and on start application reed from registry, start download for its like that

```
IUpdateSearcher updateSearcher = updateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher();
ISearchResult searchResult = updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled = 0");
```

var updateCollection = new UpdateCollection();

`for (int i = 0; i < searchResult.Updates.Count; i++)
        {
            IUpdate update = searchResult.Updates[i];
            //update id from registry
            if (update.Identity.UpdateID == "081cab8e-faf5-421b-be7c-3e796837f1ff")
            {
                updateCollection.Add(update);

                break;
            }
        }

        downloader = updateSession.CreateUpdateDownloader();
        downloader.Updates = updateCollection;

        var downloadJob = downloader.BeginDownload(new DownloadProgress(), new DownloadCompleted(), this);

        var progress = downloadJob.GetProgress();`

and in `var progress` I cat get what updates now downloading and its progress